# Let $f:S^n \to S^n$ be a continuous map. Show that the two following conditions are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $f:S^n \to S^n$ be a continuous map. Show that the two following conditions are equivalent: $$\begin{align} (i) &\ f \text{ is null-homotopic} \\ (ii) &\ \text{ There exists an continuous extension }g: \overline{B}^{n+1} \to S^n \text{ of } f. \end{align}$$

First If I suppose that $f$ is null-homotopic, then $\exists h :f \simeq c_a$, where $c_a$ is some constant map. Do I now need to somehow show that the composition of the inclusion $\iota :S^n \to \overline{B}^{n+1}$ and $f$ is the extension $g$? That is $$g:= f \circ \iota?$$ The restriction of this map to $S^n$ is $f$ so this should work?

Comment: You cannot compose $\imath$ and $f$ in this way. For this to work, $\imath$ had to in the other direction.

Comment: Hint: the homotopy gives a continuous map from $S^n+I$ to $S^n$. Can you use the fact that $c_a$ is constant to convert this into a map from $\overline B^{n+1}$ to $S^n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $h \colon f \simeq c_a$ denote the homotopy. Then $h \colon S^n \times [0,1] \to S^n$, and $h|_{S^n \times \{1\}}$ is constant. Therefore $h$ induces a map on $S^{n} \times [0,1]/S^n \times \{1\} \cong \bar B^{n+1}$ that extends $f$.

For the other direction, if $g$ is an extension of $f$, as $\bar B^{n+1}$ is contractible, there is a homotopy $k \colon g \simeq c_a$, that restricts to a homotopy for $f$.

Comment: Where do you get the statement that $h$ induces a map on $S^{n} \times [0,1]/S^n \times \{1\} \cong \bar B^{n+1}$ which extends $f$?

Comment: @localize I am guessing (not entirely sure if my argument is correct) that let's say for the case of a circle [$x^2+y^2 = 1$ and denoted by S]  when you mod out (remove) the constant map $h \mid_{S \times {1}}$ you are removing  the point $1$ so what you get is $[0,1)$ the half open interval which is then homeomorphic to $\overline{B}$